# Reporting in Rich Text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I've built an ASP.net web application which allows the users to view and make notes on a list of calendar events.  The notes are edited in a WYSIWYG editor that outputs to HTML text (but could also output to RTF), which is then saved as text in an MSSQL05 database.

Now I've got to add a printing function to the calendar application.  Prior to this version, the printing was done through SSRS05, but now that I've added rich text notes, this method will no longer work.

I can render the whole calendar in a printer-friendly format in the web browser, but my users have two issues with that:  first, I can't turn off the header and footer added during the print, and the users are a little too basic to understand how to turn it off themselves; and second, when a note gets too long, the text gets wrapped not-too-gracefully to the next page.  Unfortunately, they use IE7, so the page-break-inside attribute isn't recognized, and upgrading to IE8 or using a different browser is out of the question (I already asked :P)

So with that information, what's the best way to generate a report which features rich text?

Comment: I've also looked into Crystal, which claims to support HTML and RTF rendering, but in practice it ignores a bunch of styles (strikethrough being the largest concern of my users, and font-face being another one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest DataDynamics ActiveReports. Very powerful, lightyears ahead Crystal. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that one - it seems like it might be the closest one yet!

Comment: Just received a mail from GrapeCity announcing new version of Active Reports. Due to the fact that you're working on Asp.NET environment and they introduced a Adobe Flash! viewer, this can help you a lot, IMVHO.